# Kibana 5.x not accessible on LAN

Tags: linux, centos, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-5

I have a Centos 7 Virtualbox Virtual Machine where I installed Elasticsearch 5.x and Kibana 5.x. All good, both services started successfully. If I do `curl http://192.168.1.192:5601` on VM all is working ok, but if I try to access Kibana Web Interface from host, this is unaccessible.

Network interface of the VM is set to bridbe to host wlan0, host and vm ar connected to the same router: host ip: `192.168.1.190`, vm ip: `192.168.1.192`

In my kibana.yml I have:

```
server.port: 5601

# Specifies the address to which the Kibana server will bind. IP addresses and host names are both valid values.
# The default is 'localhost', which usually means remote machines will not be able to connect.
# To allow connections from remote users, set this parameter to a non-loopback address.
server.host: "0.0.0.0"

# Enables you to specify a path to mount Kibana at if you are running behind a proxy. This only affects
# the URLs generated by Kibana, your proxy is expected to remove the basePath value before forwarding requests
# to Kibana. This setting cannot end in a slash.
#server.basePath: ""

# The maximum payload size in bytes for incoming server requests.
#server.maxPayloadBytes: 1048576

# The Kibana server's name.  This is used for display purposes.
server.name: "elkmaster1"

# The URL of the Elasticsearch instance to use for all your queries.
elasticsearch.url: "http://localhost:9200"
```

Selinux is disabled, firewalld is disabled and I don't have any firewall software installed on that VM. [Also, I could ssh into vm from host]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

if you have firewall on your CentOs must open kibana port (5601).

for view your firewall status use:

```
sudo systemctl status firewalld.service
```

Comment: I don't have any firewall software enabled

Comment: are you sure? test out of the VM (OS) for open ports.

Comment: in windows can use this tools: https://techtalk.gfi.com/scan-open-ports-in-windows-a-quick-guide/